# ansibleのyamlでplaybookを作成した際の、各モジュールの頭にハイフンを付ける基準について

Tags: ansible, 構成管理, yaml

現在、ansibleでyamlを使って、playbookを記載しています。
サンプルをうまく使って、動かすことはできているのですが、yamlの書き方について以下の点を質問させてください。

■質問事項1
たとえば以下のようなplaybookがある場合に、文頭に「-(ハイフン)」がつくものと付かないものがあります。
調べるとシーケンスという考え方らしいのですが、「ハイフン」をつけるときとつけないときをどのように決めればいいのかおしえていただけないでしょうか。

以下、サンプル。
「- name」となっていたり、「- size」となっているところが該当箇所になります。

```
- name: Create a virtual machine on given ESXi hostname
vmware_guest:
hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip }}"
username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
validate_certs: False
folder: /DC1/vm/
name: test_vm_0001
state: poweredon
guest_id: centos64Guest
esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi_hostname }}"
disk:
- size_gb: 10
type: thin
datastore: datastore1
hardware:
memory_mb: 512
num_cpus: 4
scsi: paravirtual
networks:
- name: VM Network
mac: aa:bb:dd:aa:00:14
ip: 10.10.10.100
netmask: 255.255.255.0
device_type: vmxnet3
wait_for_ip_address: yes
delegate_to: localhost
register: deploy_vm
```

以上です、よろしくおねがいいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11197637286

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YAMLにおいて、行頭の`-`は**リスト**（配列）を表します。リストは、複数のものを並べるための記法です。

質問者さんのYAMLドキュメントを正しくインデントすると以下のようになります。これは全体として、[vmware_guestモジュール](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_guest_module.html)を実行するタスク`Create a virtual machine on given ESXi hostname`を定義するものであることが分かります。

```
- name: Create a virtual machine on given ESXi hostname
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: False
    folder: /DC1/vm/
    name: test_vm_0001
    state: poweredon
    guest_id: centos64Guest
    esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi_hostname }}"
    disk:
      - size_gb: 10
        type: thin
        datastore: datastore1
    hardware:
      memory_mb: 512
      num_cpus: 4
      scsi: paravirtual
    networks:
      - name: VM Network
        mac: aa:bb:dd:aa:00:14
        ip: 10.10.10.100
        netmask: 255.255.255.0
        device_type: vmxnet3
    wait_for_ip_address: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: deploy_vm
```

`hostname`や`username`以下、たくさんのオプションが`vmware_guest`モジュールへのオプションとして渡されていることが分かります。

モジュールのオプションの中には、**リスト**で指定すべきものがあります。この例では`disk`と`networks`が該当します。実際、例えば`disk`については、上記のリファレンスから引用すると次のように書いてあり、リストを指定する必要があることが分かります。

> A **list** of disks to add.
>   This parameter is case sensitive.
>
> （後略，強調は引用者）

この例では、`disk`の下にある`-`は1つですから、以下に示す1つのオブジェクトだけからなるリストを渡していることになります。

```
size_gb: 10
type: thin
datastore: datastore1
```

例えば2つのディスクが必要ならば、次のようにリスト記法を用いて指定することになります。`-`を先頭とする2つの行は、それぞれのオブジェクトの先頭となっていることが分かります。

```
disk:
  - size_gb: 10
    type: thin
    datastore: datastore1
  - size_mb: 500
    type: thin
    datastore: datastore2
```

下のほうにある`networks`についても同様で、これも`-`が1つだけであることから、以下のオブジェクト1つからなるリストです。

```
name: VM Network
mac: aa:bb:dd:aa:00:14
ip: 10.10.10.100
netmask: 255.255.255.0
device_type: vmxnet3
```

もし2つ以上のネットワークが必要ならば、上と同様に`-`を先頭とする複数のオブジェクトを並べればよいことになります。

---

> 「ハイフン」をつけるときとつけないときをどのように決めればいいのかおしえていただけないでしょうか。

という質問に対する答えとしては、使用したいモジュール（今回の場合はvmware_guest）のどのオプションにリストを渡すべきなのかを、ドキュメントを頼りに調べましょう、ということになります。

---

なお、一番最初の行（`- name: Create a virtual machine on given ESXi hostname`）の行頭にもハイフンがありますが、これも当然リストの記法です。というのも、このファイルはタスクの**リスト**を記述しなければいけないからです。今回定義されているタスクは1つだけですが、複数のタスクを定義する場合はやはりリストの記法を用いてタスクを並べていくことになります。